# Supremum of a set and Supremum of a function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Why $\sup (f+g) \leq \sup\ f + \sup\ g$, where f & g are functions? while sup (A + B) = sup A + sup B, where A and B are sets?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one writes $A+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets, one typically means the set containing *all* of the sums that can be formed by adding one element from $A$ and one element from $B$. Therefore, the supremum of $A+B$ is the sum of the two supremums.

On the other hand, when one adds two functions together, the two functions are only added *pointwise*. Therefore, intuitively, if $f$ attains its maximum $y$ at a point $x$ and $g$ attains its maximum $y'$ at a point $x'\neq x$, there is a priori no reason why $f+g$ should attain $y+y'$.

Comment: Thank you so much so clear answer :), but how can I prove what you said?

Comment: I think you should open a new question stating exactly what you would like to prove. It is quite probable that, in the process of formulating precisely the question, you will come up with the answer yourself :-)